# Remove/Prevent First Blank from Oracle CSV MARKUP output file

Tags: windows, oracle, oracle12c, sqlplus

I am currently writing scripts to output table data to CSV files so that they can be ingested into another platform. I'd much rather use the `set markup CSV on quote on;` SQL option to generate my output file. as it makes the script much cleaner and a whole lot simpler to write.

The problem, however, is that no matter how hard I try, I cannot seem to find an option that will prevent the output file from starting with a blank line. I need the column headers in the very first line and not in the second line.

The scripts need to run on a Windows Server against an Oracle 12c (12.1.0.2.0) Database, using SQLPLUS to execute the SQL commands and PowerShell/batch as the scripting wrapper.

After searching for some time and trying various options that only seem to have any effect on older approaches to CSV outputs. Eventually, I found the Oracle documentation for the SET command and discovered that things like `SET NEWPAGE`, `SET TRIMSPOOL` have no effect when using `SET MARK[UP]`.

Oracle SET Command documentation is here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-0AA910C4-C22A-4A9E-BE13-AAA059CC7919

Is there a simple way to get rid of or suppress the first line that is blank? I really don't want to have to write further file processing scripts that go and remove the line from the file using PowerShell/Batch. That just seems like a really dumb thing to have to do...

A simplified version of my SQL is below and the output still includes the blank first line.

```
column thespoolfile new_value thespoolfile
select 'D:\Temp\outfile-detail-' || TO_CHAR( sysdate, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI' ) || '.csv' as thespoolfile from dual;

set markup csv on quote on;
SET FEEDBACK OFF;
set trimspool on;
SET HEADSEP off;
SET SQLBLANKLINES off;
SET termout OFF;
spool &thespoolfile;
set define off;
select *
  from <table>;
spool off;
exit
```

Comment: Can you try to add a "set pages 0" and remove the "set define off"?

Comment: `set pages 0` will suppress the heading also.

Comment: @MartinSchapendonk `SET DEFINE OFF` is required as I use a `REPLACE` with a string containing an `&`. without the `SET DEFINE OFF` this breaks. The `SET PAGES 0` removes the header completely, so also not helpful

Comment: Is using SQL\*Plus an absolute requirement, or can you switch to [SQLcl](https://www.oracle.com/uk/database/technologies/appdev/sqlcl.html), which has better formatting options?

Comment: @Giles How did you solve this problem?

Comment: @Steve Still haven't solved it tbh... my clients deal with the blank line...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following option

```
SET NEWPAGE NONE
```

It will suppress the first blank line, which is bothering you.

Cheers!!

Comment: This answer does not output CSV as requested.

Comment: One second, This was a sample code. Resolution of the issue is `SET NEWPAGE NONE`. Put it in your code and it will **suppress the first blank line.** Now, see my answer

Comment: Incorrect, please refer to the documentation and to my question which EXPLICITLY explains that it [`SET NEWPAGE`] has no effect when using the `SET MARK[UP]` option

Comment: You are right, Not giving me result when used with Markup.